# BottlePy App and CherryPy server not logging access

Tags: python, cherrypy, bottle

I'm serving a BottlePy App with CherryPy like this:

```py
import cherrypy
from myapp import MyApp
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

appdir = '/path/to/app'
app = MyApp(appdir)

session_opts = {
    'session.timeout': 600,  # 10 minutes
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.auto': True,
    'session.data_dir': appdir + '/auth/data'
}
app = SessionMiddleware(app, session_opts)

cherrypy.tree.graft(app, '/')
cherrypy.config.update({
    'log.screen': False,
    'log.access_file': appdir + '/front_end/cherrypy.access.log',
    'log.error_file': appdir + '/front_end/cherrypy.error.log',
    'server.socket_port': 8080,
    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'
})

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Everything seems to be working properly, but `cherrypy.access.log` remains totally empty, while `cherrypy.error.log` reads:

```
[30/Dec/2014:11:04:55] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[30/Dec/2014:11:04:55] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[30/Dec/2014:11:04:55] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[30/Dec/2014:11:04:56] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
[30/Dec/2014:11:04:56] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

But nothing else, no access logs, even after serving content.

I also tried

```py
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

# Instead of the cherrypy.* calls

server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), app)
server.start()
```

but it will print the same as above, but no access logs. Could not find any further documentation on logging and BottlePy integration.

Comment: does the user running your app have rights to write to the file?

Comment: Yes, permissions are okay. The access log gets created and the error log has some lines.

Answer (score 2):

The app you're running is not native CherryPy one, and `graft`ing basically bypasses most of CP's internals, most likely including access logging.

Since you don't use any CherryPy's features besides basic WSGI publishing, you may be better off using one of the more serving-oriented (and more recent) solutions like uWSGI, Gunicorn or nginx/Apache+plugins.

Comment: I was trying CherryPy because it is suggested in the BottlePy docs. Perhaps not the best choice. What would be the best choice for high performance threaded deployment of a Bottle App?

Comment: @jpcgt I gave you some popular choices, select which suits you best. Note that since Python has its GIL issue, you should avoid native threaded servers when you need performance. uWSGI and Gunicorn use process-based workers and are safe in this regard; not sure about the plug-ins though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `log.screen` to `True` to enable both error and access logs.

See (old) docs: https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cplogging.html

Comment: It doesn't make a difference on the log files. And as far as I understand `log.screen` is for logging to standard output, not log files.

Comment: That's wasn't my understanding of the docs...have you tried it to see what happens?